# sudo -s takes a long time to execute and prompts sudo: was not possible to resolve machine XXX

Tags: sudo, hostname

I do not know what is wrong but now, whenever i use a sudo command it takes a long time to execute and prompts:

```
sudo: was not possible to resolve machine XXX
```

then it executes. It seems that is searching for the machine name like a dns and the time it takes is a network timeout. Can anyone help me? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe there is something wrong in your host file. You can read it by using.

```
cat /etc/hosts
```

EDIT: it has to match your /etc/hostname

Comment: Yes you are wright! the /etc/hosts much have 127.0.0.1  XX where XX is the exact text that is in the /etc/hostname. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your linux bos is trying to resolve the hostname which is not setup in your hosts file. If you type the word **hostname** should print the actual host name setup.

```
sudo nano /etc/hosts #opens the file for editing
127.0.0.1 myhostname #add this to the file and Ctrl+O to save, Ctrl+X to exit
```

That should sort you out but you can also trace the syscall to see where it's spending alot of time executing

```
sudo strace -r -o trace.log sudo echo hello
```

**NB:** With strace, each line starts with the time taken since entering the previous syscall.

Regards Douglas